# Merge two general formatted cells in Excel (one holding a date, the other a time) but keep their respective formats

Tags: excel, formula

I have an Excel spread sheet that I need to import into an SQL Server database in a specific format. The sheet contains the data I need but in an incompatible format for the DateTime field in Excel.

I have the following cells currently formatted as 'general':

```
DATE         | TIME    | DATETIME
-----------------------------------
2014-08-01   | 23:45   |
```

I want to combine DATE and TIME to get a DATETIME value of '2014-08-01 23:45:00.000'

I have the following (if DATE was cell G2):

```
=TEXT(G2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&" " & TEXT(H2, [what should I put here?])
```

But as you see I simply cant work out what to put in the final part of the formula to make this display as I need.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as you expect if you do this:

```
=TEXT(G2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&" "&TEXT(H2,"hh:mm:ss.000")
                                         ^^^^^^^
```

The difference from the answer given by pnuts is that if your time contains seconds (even with millisecond accuracy), the above would catch and format it correctly whereas the other answer hard codes the seconds with "00.000" (so you lose any seconds you may have).

If you never have this case of seconds in your data, then either is fine.

Comment: Many thanks! I have just discovered I DO have seconds in another cell. Also, I think your answer provides an additional level of information many others may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(G2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&" "&TEXT(H2,"hh:mm")&":00.000"
```

Comment: Many thanks, I am very grateful. This works well but actually I do have seconds held in another column (where I need to do a similar formatting) so I will select the answer by @djikay as 'accepted'. I appreciate your help and advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
=(TEXT(TODAY(),"m/dd/yy")&" "&TEXT("17:00","hh:mm")) -> convert text to date format
```

It means you can calculate with the date format.
Thank for your sharing !